# Drawing dashed line in Sprite Kit using SKShapeNode and CGPath

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, cgpath, skshapenode

I want to draw a dashed line in my sprite kit game, I can use SKShapeNode node to draw a normal line like the following:

```
 UIBezierPath *_path=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
 //1
 CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(100,100);
 CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(150,150);
 [_path moveToPoint:point1];
 [_path addLineToPoint:point2];
 //2
 SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];
 line.path = _path.CGPath;
```

I tried to set a dashed pattern to UIBezierPath like this:

```
// adding this code at location 1 or 2 above but no effect
CGFloat dashes[] = {6, 2};
[_path setLineDash:dashes count:2 phase:0];
```

but the dashed pattern is not applied.

I also tried to create a dashed copy of CGPath directly from UIBezierpath.CGPath property as:

```
 CGFloat dashes[] = {6, 2};
 CGPathRef aCGPath= CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(_path.CGPath,NULL,0,dashes,2);
line.path = aCGPath;
```

but also the same.

I really appreciate if someone could explain what is the problem and how can I draw a dashed line between two points by applying dashed cgpath to skshapenode.

Edit: I know for this simple example I could divide the distance between these two points to  small fixed distances and moving and drawing dashed line by bezeirpath but consider a free hand path with points came from touches, it is a very complex and inefficient to redraw the path with fixed length points then draw dashes. I wonder if there is a way to apply the dashed pattern to the path and making skshapenode to use it that is my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anyone is still interested in a simple answer to this question:

Use `CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath` to create a *dashed* copy of `- [UIBezierCurve CGPath]`

```
CGPathRef CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(
   CGPathRef path,
   const CGAffineTransform *transform,
   CGFloat phase,
   const CGFloat *lengths,
   size_t count
);
```

and add it to the `SKShapeNode`'s `path` property.

Example:

```
    // creates a dashed pattern
    CGFloat pattern[2];
    pattern[0] = 10.0;
    pattern[1] = 10.0;
    CGPathRef dashed =
    CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath([bezierPath CGPath],
                                  NULL,
                                  0,
                                  pattern,
                                  2);

    self.myShapeNode.path = dashed;

    CGPathRelease(dashed);
```

EDIT: For performance, you can add an `SKShapeNode` to an `SKEffectNode` and set the `shouldRasterize` property to `YES`.

Comment: your solution worked great! But I don't understand your performance comment. You're saying add the shapenode to an effectnode, then add the effectnode to the scene? As set the rasterize on the effect node? Could you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: If you use an `SKShapeNode` as-is it will draw the path every frame. If you use an `SKEffectNode` as described above it will cache a bitmap version of the path so will render it much more quickly (only useful for a path that you don't expect to change very often).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, it was long time, I managed to solve that problem by not using SKShapeNode at all because of performance and weird memory leaks issues. I finally used SKSpriteNode to draw the dashed line (each single dash is an SKSpriteNode), to maintain performance I used single SKTexture of the "Dash Image", and the result was perfect. 
I will mark your answer as accepted so anyone interested in a solution by using SKShapeNode will find it here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code at location 1 to something like this:

```
UIBezierPath *_path=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(100,100);
CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(150,150);
CGFloat deltaX = 1;
CGFloat deltaY = 1;
CGPoint tmpPoint = point1;
[_path moveToPoint:point1];
while(tmpPoint.x<point2.x && tmpPoint.y<point2.y){
    tmpPoint.x+=deltaX;
    tmpPoint.y+=deltaY;
    if((tmpPoint.y-point1.y)%2==1){
       [_path addLineToPoint:tmpPoint];
    }else{
      [_path moveToPoint:tmpPoint];
    }
}
// If the line is not a 45 degree straight line
// Please modify the while loop accordingly
[_path addLineToPoint:point2];
```