# Drawing dashed line in Sprite Kit using SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgpath, skshapenode

[I fount this solution but I can't make it into swift code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778681/drawing-dashed-line-in-sprite-kit-using-skshapenode-and-cgpath)

This what I try

```
var pattern[2]:CGFloat; this 

var dashed: CGPathRef = CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(path, transform, phase, lengths, count);

var myShapeNode: SKShapeNode!;

        var CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath:CGPathRef;
```

Comment: Where do you fail? Show us your try.

Comment: please add that code to your question.

Comment: question is very badly asked. code is poorly formatted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how you can draw a dashed line in swift. You can change the parameters as you want.

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
let startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 250)
let endPoint = CGPointMake(450, 250)
bezierPath.moveToPoint(startPoint)
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(endPoint)

var pattern : [CGFloat] = [10.0, 10.0]
let dashed = CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath (bezierPath.CGPath, nil, 0, pattern, 2)

var shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: dashed)
shapeNode.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
self.addChild(shapeNode)
```

Comment: In Swift 3 `CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath` has been replaced by `path.copy(dashingWithPhase:lengths:)`

Answer (score 7):

In swift 4:

```
    let square = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))
    let pattern : [CGFloat] = [4.0, 4.0]

    let dashed = square.path?.copy(dashingWithPhase: 1, lengths: pattern)

    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: dashed!)
    shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    shapeNode.fillColor = SKColor.clear
    shapeNode.strokeColor = SKColor.red
    shapeNode.lineWidth = 2
    self.addChild(shapeNode)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to work out how to apply this same principal to an SKShapeNode like I was, here is an example. A rectangle with a blue dashed line.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

let square = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))
let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20.0)

var pattern : [CGFloat] = [2.0, 2.0]
let dashed = CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath (square.path, nil, 0, pattern, 2)

var shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: dashed!)
shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

[image: A square with a dashed line]

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
if let path = path?.copy(dashingWithPhase: 1, lengths: [5, 5]) {
    let line = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    line.strokeColor = .white
    self.addChild(line)
}
```

[image]

Comment: whilst this looks great, for me it lacks some extra information that actually helps you produce the path in the image.  where are the points that define that curve, and where does "path" come from in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the solution provided by Mike Glukhov above, this is my solution:

```
func drawTrace(pointArray: Array<CGPoint>) {
    if pointArray.count > 1 {
        let pattern : [CGFloat] = [10.0, 10.0]

        let path = CGMutablePath.init()

        // start at the first point.
        path.move(to: pointArray[0])

        // now add all of the others.
        for p in 1 ..< pointArray.count {
            path.addLine(to: pointArray[p])
        }

        // create the dashed path.
        let dashedPath = path.copy(dashingWithPhase: 1, lengths: pattern)

        let dashName = "dash"

        // now create the node
        let line = SKShapeNode(path: dashedPath)
        line.strokeColor = .white
        line.name = dashName

        if let parent = self.parent {
            if let oldLine = parent.childNode(withName: dashName) {
                oldLine.removeFromParent()
            }

            parent.addChild(line)
        }
    }
}
```