# Display upperLimit SKRange

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, swift5

So here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ship1 = [2,1]
    var ship2 = [1,2]

    let jonahSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jonah_spaceship")
    let georgeSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "george_spaceship")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //var jonahFrames = [SKTexture]()
        jonahSpriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: 30, y: frame.midY)
        jonahSpriteNode.size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        addChild(jonahSpriteNode)

        georgeSpriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: 628, y: frame.midY)
        georgeSpriteNode.size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        addChild(georgeSpriteNode)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            var touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            var angle1 = atan2(jonahSpriteNode.position.y - touchLocation.y , jonahSpriteNode.position.x - touchLocation.x)
            var angle = angle1 - CGFloat(Double.pi / 1)

            makeCircularRange(to: jonahSpriteNode)

            let rotate = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle, duration: 1.0)
            let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x, y: touchLocation.y), duration: 2.5)
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([rotate, move])
            jonahSpriteNode.run(sequence)
        }
    }

    func makeCircularRange(to node: SKNode) {
        let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: 0, upperLimit: 400)
        let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: .zero)
        node.constraints = [constraint]
    }

}
```

I wanted to display the SKRange by showing upperLimit in a certain color. I tried making nodes around the limit and then coloring the nodes but it just showed a bunch of errors. If you have any ideas please answer.

Something like this:
[image: With the sprite node in the middle to show where you can move]

The sprite node will be in the center and the circle will show where it can move.

Comment: SKRange is a abstraction for complete one constraint, what do you want to draw on screen? Can you add example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a circular shape using range.upperLimit as a radius an add to scene.

```
func drawCircularRangeBy(range: SKRange) {
    let radius = range.upperLimit
    let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
    node.strokeColor = .white
    addChild(node)
}
```

Take a look of this example: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/CircularRange/CircularRange/GameScene.swift

If you really need dots instead of a line please see this answer: [Drawing dashed line in Sprite Kit using SKShapeNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072879/drawing-dashed-line-in-sprite-kit-using-skshapenode)

[image]